# How can I find ETFs whose portfolio intersects as much as possible with another ETF?

Tags: etf, portfolio, alternatives

I want to find alternatives to an ETF.

How can I find ETFs whose portfolio intersects as much as possible with this ETF?

Comment: I cant understand what you are asking gramatically, please rewrite this question to be more clear

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: For what purpose? Why not just invest in the "original" ETF?

Comment: @DStanley There can be many reasons. You might want to find an ETF with a lower expense ratio that has most of the same stocks. Or you might like most of the holdings in the portfolio, but you want to avoid one that has a high weight that you think is too risky.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various comparison tools available.

My broker offers a Mutual Fund/ETF Replicator tool that suggests alternatives with lower fees.

There are various internet tools as well.   Here's an example of one at:https://www.etfrc.com/funds/overlap.php

It indicates that the SPY has 505 holdings,  VOO has  512 holdings and that there are 503 overlapping constituents.

There are also correlation tools available that will compare the performance of ETFs over a designated time period.

Comment: May I ask which broker you use, Bob?

Comment: I have three brokers but I do the vast majority of my trading at Interactive Brokers (it has the tool that  I mentioned if that's what you're after).